# Kubernetes 1.14.2 HA Master NGINX load balancer log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43148: remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, handshake

This is driving me crazy, I am NO Kubernetes expert but I am also not a novice.

I have tried unsuccessfully for three days to get past this issue but I can't and I am at the end of my rope.

I can query the cluster from my desktop after I copied the certificates from (kube-apiserver-1:/etc/kubernetes/pki/*) to my desktop.

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get nodes
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kube-apiserver-1   Ready    master   71m   v1.14.2
```

The Kubernetes cluster appears healthy when I query the kube-system pods:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get pods
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-fb8b8dccf-6c85q                    1/1     Running   3          65m
coredns-fb8b8dccf-qwxlp                    1/1     Running   3          65m
kube-apiserver-kube-apiserver-1            1/1     Running   2          72m
kube-controller-manager-kube-apiserver-1   1/1     Running   2          72m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-phntk                1/1     Running   2          62m
kube-proxy-swxrz                           1/1     Running   2          65m
kube-scheduler-kube-apiserver-1            1/1     Running   1          54m
```

but when I query the api kubelet:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-apiserver-kube-apiserver-1 
...
I0526 04:33:51.523828       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43122: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:51.537258       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43124: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:51.540617       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43126: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.333817       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43130: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.334354       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43128: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.335570       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43132: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.336703       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43134: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.338792       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43136: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.391557       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43138: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.396566       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43140: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.519666       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43142: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.524702       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43144: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.537127       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43146: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.550177       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43150: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 04:33:52.550613       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:43148: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

On the NGINX load balancer (IP: 192.168.5.32) I have configured the TCP passthrough option as specified in the Kubernetes documentation:

```
upstream kubernetes-api-cluster {
   server 192.168.5.19:6443;
   server 192.168.5.29:6443;
}
server {
   listen 6443;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/kube-apiserver.key;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
   proxy_pass kubernetes-api-cluster;
}
```

I can query the API server directly from the NGINX LB (IP: 192.168.5.32):

```
$ curl -v https://192.168.5.29:6443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://192.168.5.29:6443/
*   Trying 192.168.5.29...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.5.29 (192.168.5.29) port 6443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=kube-apiserver
*  start date: May 26 03:39:36 2019 GMT
*  expire date: May 25 03:39:36 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "192.168.5.29" matched cert's IP address!
*  issuer: CN=kubernetes
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55840f1d9900)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: 192.168.5.29:6443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
```

I can also query the api using the DNS entry to the api as specified in the documents:

```
curl -v https://kube-apiserver.mydomain.com:6443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://kube-apiserver.mydomain.com:6443/
*   Trying 10.50.1.50...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to kube-apiserver.mydomain.com (10.50.1.50) port 6443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=kube-apiserver
*  start date: May 26 03:39:36 2019 GMT
*  expire date: May 25 03:39:36 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "kube-apiserver.mydomain.com" matched cert's "kube-apiserver.mydomain.com"
*  issuer: CN=kubernetes
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x564287cbd900)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: kube-apiserver.mydomain.com:6443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
```

I can query the api server using curl as well on the API server:

```
curl -v https://kube-apiserver.mydomain.com:6443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://kube-apiserver.mydomain.com:6443/
*   Trying 10.50.1.50...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to kube-apiserver.epc-instore.com (10.50.1.50) port 6443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=kube-apiserver
*  start date: May 26 03:39:36 2019 GMT
*  expire date: May 25 03:39:36 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "kube-apiserver.mydomain.com" matched cert's "kube-apiserver.mydomain.com"
*  issuer: CN=kubernetes
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5628b9dbc900)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: kube-apiserver.mydomain.com:6443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
```

The manifest on the api server contains:

```
cat /etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-apiserver.yaml
...
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=192.168.5.29
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-servers=http://etcd-cluster.mydomain.com:2379
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.14.2
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
...
```

If you have any idea or hints on how to fix this I am all ears.  I am so frustrated with this issue, it really has gotten to me at this point.  I will continue to work on it but if anyone has a clue about this issue and can help it will be great.

Thank you.

Comment: `bad certificate` indicates that the server you're trying to connect to requires a client certificate and you're either not providing one or sending one that the server is not accepting. The `--client-ca-file` in your `kube-apiserver.yaml` manifest enables client certificate authentication. In your various `curl` output examples you only show the request, not the responses, so it's not possible to say what the server is responding - I guess it's not a 200 OK response?

Comment: OK, so this is starting to feel like the layer 7 I am using NGINX is supposed to be a layer 4 LB that forwards the client certificates.  While in the documentation for creating a Kubernetes HA (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#first-steps-for-both-methods) makes it seem like it should work the layer 7 NGINX server may not be forwarding the client certificates as I have read in a few other questions like this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/835984/nginx-reverse-proxy-passthrough-of-client-tls-certificate.  WHY DOES IT NOT MAKE THIS CLEAR IN THE DOCS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual root cause of the original issue was (citing the author of this post @Daniel Maldonado):

> This was my mistake, I had a firewall configuration error and all
>   tests indicated that it was the load balancer probing the
>   kube-apiserver when in fact it was not. The issue was completely local
>   to the api-server itself. If anyone gets to this point please verify
>   that ALL ports are available to the API server from itself i.e.
>   loopback.

Answer (score 0):

Your current nginx config isn't setting up a client cert. `ssl_certificate` is the server cert, if you want it to present a client cert to `kubernetes-api-cluster` you'll have to configure nginx to forward the incoming client certificate. I've previously done this using `proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert` ([documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables))

```
upstream kubernetes-api-cluster { 
    server 192.168.5.19:6443;
    server 192.168.5.29:6443; 
} 

server { 
    listen 6443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/kube-apiserver.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
    proxy_pass kubernetes-api-cluster; 

    #forward incoming client certificate
    ssl_verify_client optional; #requests the client certificate and verifies it if the certificate is present
    proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
}
```

Comment: Won't this make every client request look like it is coming from the same "user"?  What do you suggest I use as clientcert.pem?

Comment: @DanielMaldonado You are correct, it will. Are you going to be providing distinct client certificates from every client connecting to the API via nginx?

Comment: @DanielMaldonado And as to what I'd use as `clientcert.pem`. I'd use any certificate that validates with the CA you've configured in `--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`

Comment: Every node that belongs to the cluster will have its own set of certificates.  I believe your suggestion would make the entire cluster insecure.  Can a layer 7 NGINX LB forward certificates?

Comment: If you want to use mutual TLS then I agree. It would make the cluster insecure. You could use it just for testing though. I did forward client certs in some old nginx configuration. Let me see if I can dig it up

Comment: You know, the one thing that is blowing my mind is that I cannot be the ONLY one having this problem.  I have no idea how other people have configured an HA cluster behind a NGINX LB.  There is NO way this was easy for anyone.

Comment: I provided an update, see if that doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: Arggghhhh... May 26 14:44:28 load-balancer nginx[26460]: nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kubernetes-api:13

Comment: So I put the stuff in a location block and I get:  May 26 14:54:45 load-balancer nginx[26605]: nginx: [emerg] no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify

Comment: I wasn't able to find my old config that forwarded the incoming client cert, but I might have some more time to look for it tomorrow. Could you try `ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca` ([documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client))

Comment: Nope, that did not work either.  Still getting the original error:  I0526 15:55:51.990243       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:36638: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0526 15:55:52.102702       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.5.32:36640: remote error: tls: bad certificate.  What was that configuration that was sending the client cert?  I may have to do this just to get past this error then come back and troubleshoot this more.

Comment: Check the [edit revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56313720/revisions) to the answer. That being said, do you actually send a client certificate from the clients going through nginx?

Comment: OK, maybe I should explain this a bit more.  I do not go beyond the point of configuring a single api server before I start checking for this exception.  So any errors that happen on the server have to do with the server acting as a client though the NGINX load balancer.  So the sever itself is complaining that it cannot validate the client because the NGINX is not forwarding the client certificates from a layer 7 LB.

Comment: After all this work, the thing that is failing the is actual NGINX health check.  Does anyone have a TCP load balancer configuration that specifies ...:6443/healthz as a health check.  I already have a layer 4 configuration but that does not work at all.

Comment: @DanielMaldonado Unfortunately I was unable to find that old config. It was part of a proof-of-concept I did a while back but it was never version controlled.

Comment: Not to worry, the problem is the health check from the load balancer.  Since it does not have a certificate it is throwing that exception.  It would be great if we had a health check that did NOT require a certificate :-/  This is still an issue and I will have to work on that once the cluster is completely stable, for now we just turned heal checks off in the LB.  This is not an ideal solution but it got us past the point of constantly seeing the exception in the log.

Comment: It was interesting for me to learn, that 'TLS handshake error' seen in kube-apiserver logs actually happens during health checks.
@Daniel Maldonado, would you mind summarizing your findings in the comments in form of post update, or wiki post.

Comment: This was my mistake, I had a firewall configuration error and all tests indicated that it was the load balancer probing the kube-apiserver when in fact it was not.  The issue was completely local to the api-server itself.  If anyone gets to this point please verify that ALL ports are available to the API server from itself i.e.  loopback.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a troubleshooting idea to really target the source of the problem.
 If you can do:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf get nodes
```

from the api server and you get a response then the problem is NOT the load balancer.  To further prove this you can copy the appropriate certificates and files to a remote workstation and do the same:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig [workstation location]/admin.conf get nodes
```

This second one obviously implies that you have direct access to the load balancer.
If this works too you have confirmation that the certificates are being passed through the TCP load balancer.

However, the error will persist as the load balancer has a check "availability" of a backend server.  This check does NOT use a certificate which produces the exception.